# Register multiple SelectionKey

Tags: java, nio, channel

I am working with Java selectors in NIO. I am registering my selection key/ interest key with the particular channels and selectors. Now, my requirement is to have two or more interest sets for a particular selector.

What I did is make two selectionkeys with different selection options as follows:

```
    try {
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel channel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        //FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream("").getChannel();

        channel.configureBlocking(false);

        SelectionKey key1 = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        SelectionKey key2 = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My question is, is there any way i can avoid making two diffrent keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can binary-or the keys together to create a single interest:

```
SelectionKey key = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

Comment: The more common name is "bitwise-or" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR

Answer (score 1):

An old question, though needs attention.

Note that calling `register` twice on the same channel doesn't add additional registration but replaces the previous one.

The code presented by the OP has several issues worth attention:

```
try {
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel channel = ServerSocketChannel.open();

    channel.configureBlocking(false);

    //====================================================================
    // NOTE:
    // this is not good - see notes below...
    //====================================================================

    SelectionKey key1 = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    SelectionKey key2 = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

    //====================================================================

    // NOTE 1:
    // the 2nd call to channel.register causes the channel to be registered
    // only for OP_WRITE, replacing the registration for OP_READ.
    // So both lines together makes the first one redundant 'dead code'.

    // NOTE 2:
    // the key returned in both calls would be the same as the key is
    // associated with the channel, regardless of the events we register for 
    // (changing the registration doesn't change the SelectionKey, it only
    // sets another registration for this key).

    // NOTE 3:
    // ServerSocketChannel should not be registered for OP_READ, OP_WRITE...
    // ServerSocketChannel should be registered for OP_ACCEPT
    // You may register SocketChannel to OP_READ and OP_WRITE

    //====================================================================

} catch (IOException e) { // ...
```

So, as already noted, the correct way is to use bitwise-or, with the following additional fixes:

```
    SocketChannel clientChannel = serverSockChannel.accept();
    clientChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    SelectionKey key =
      clientChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

It is not just *better way* for registering two events -- ***it doesn't work otherwise***.